# Margin next to contenteditable

Tags: html, css

There is margin next to the contenteditable div that I cannot get rid of. Also it makes it so the svg that should be next to the contenteditable appears below even though the flex-colums and the flex-column should make it so the svg is next to it.

```
<div class="flex-columns">
       <div contenteditable class="form-input flex-column"  style="width: 400px;"></div>
       <div class="flex-column">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="black" 
            width="18px" height="18px"><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/><path d="M2.01 21L23 
            12 2.01 3 2 10l15 2-15 2z"/></svg>
       </div>
</div>
```

```
.sevenhundred-container{
    width: 700px;
}
.flex-column {
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-basis: 0;
}
.flex-columns {
    flex-direction: column;
}
.form-input {
    padding: 8px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
    font-size: 13px;
    
}
```

Comment: You are specifying a flex rule, but the flex display for the parent is not set. Show the result you want on the screenshot.

Comment: https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img922/622/8vMqVM.png  

This is what it looks like now I just want the send icon to be next to the input section

Comment: I gave you the answer. Did this answer help you? If helped, mark the answer as solved.

Answer (score 0):

Was such a result necessary?

```css
.sevenhundred-container{
    width: 700px;
}
.flex_parent {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.form-input {
    padding: 8px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    /*width: calc(100% - 20px);*/
    font-size: 13px;
    flex: 0 0 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex_parent">
       <div contenteditable class="form-input flex-column"></div>

            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="black" 
            width="18px" height="18px"><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/><path d="M2.01 21L23 
            12 2.01 3 2 10l15 2-15 2z"/></svg>

</div>
```